# Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with joining the file `rocketchat-livechat.min.js`.

Error is:

> Refused to execute script from '...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        (function(w, d, s, u) {
        w.RocketChat = function(c) { w.RocketChat._.push(c) }; w.RocketChat._ = []; w.RocketChat.url = u;
        var h = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s);
        j.async = true; j.src = 'rocketchat-livechatmin.js';
        h.parentNode.insertBefore(j, h);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'xxx');
    </script>       
</body>
```

The file is in the same directory as the html document.
Has anyone had a similar problem? What can be done to solve it? 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe you are telling the wrong Content-Type to the browser. It should be `text/javascript` for JS files.

Comment: It also doesn't work :( @MaximeLaunois

Comment: @sylwia.kol what doesn't work? Did you check what content-type is sent? Could it be that you recieve a 404-page when trying to load the js?

Comment: wait, did you forget a `.` in here `j.src = 'rocketchat-livechatmin.js';` shouldn't this end on `.min.js`?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have mentioned that you have problem joining `rocketchat-livechat.min.js`. But in your code, you have a ***typo in line 6***. This one

> j.async = true; j.src = 'rocketchat-livechatmin.js';

Replace that line with correct file-name by this:

```
j.async = true; j.src = 'rocketchat-livechat.min.js';
```

Comment: I've changed this and there is still the same problem :/

Comment: :( !  `(window, document, 'script', 'xxx');` here `xxx`, is it ok?

Comment: it's here instead of protected link :)

Comment: didn't understand . Is it working now changing `xx` with appropriate value ?